# Does the C standard require the size of an array of n elements to be n times the size of an element?

Tags: c, arrays, size, language-lawyer

Does the C standard require that the size of an array of *n* elements be *n* times the size of an element, either by explicit statement or by rigorous logical deduction from its requirements?

For example, could `int (*x)[5] = malloc(5 * sizeof **x);` fail to request sufficient space for an array of five `int`?

C 2011 [N1570] 6.5.3.4 7 shows an example of computing the number of elements in an array as `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`. However, examples are not a normative part of the standard (per paragraph 8 of the forward).

6.2.5 20 says an array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular type but is silent about the total memory required.

This is solely a language-lawyer question; actual implementations are irrelevant. (To appease those who want concrete examples, hypothesize a C implementation that requires additional memory management for large arrays, so creating an array requires creating some additional data to help manage the memory.)

Comment: "could int (*x)[5] = malloc(5 * sizeof **x); fail to request sufficient space for an array of five int" sounds unclear as obviously a `malloc()` request could fail by returning `NULL`.  Perhaps the question needs re-wording.

Comment: @chux: That’s why I wrote “fail to request” rather than “fail to allocate.” Sure the allocation can fail, but the request was made. Did it request enough or did it fail to request enough?

Comment: Hmmm, Code can allocate via `p = calloc(n, sizeof *p)` a memory block of size `n * sizeof *p`.  This memory block size can exceed `SIZE_MAX`.  But then `p` is not an array `n` of T, only a pointer to T.  So I do not think this qualifies as a counter example.

Comment: Wow, I've seen some language-lawyers before (and been one of them myself), but questioning the size of an array is a whole another level!

Comment: I'm not seeing anything here that talks about the possibility that the array may have a header.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Wait until you see the follow-up question.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The really old docs I learned on suggested that sizeof(struct {int x; char y;}) would be 3, but the array size would be 4. I believe that compiler was simply nonconforming.

Comment: EricPostpischil: I'm scared...! @Joshua: I don't have a reference handy, but from what I remember, the `sizeof` an object is *by definition* the offset of the next instance of an object in an array, so yes that compiler must have been non-conforming.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The follow-up is that `malloc` is specified to allocate memory for an object of the requested size. Just one object. So, after a successful `malloc` in `int *x = malloc(2 * sizeof *x);`, can we use both `x[0]` and `x[1]`? That is two objects, not one. Sure, the space is there for them, but are the semantics for `x[1]` defined?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The array *is* one object -- the array -- so you're at least allowed to do that if you cast to `int(*)[2]`. And there's at least one clause that says *"...an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object)"* in the subscripting section, so the two are seen as equivalently permitted (as long as you write before reading).

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, you could cast to `int (*)[2]`. So `int *x = * (int (*)[2]) malloc(2 * sizeof *x);` would be fine. That gets space for an array of two `int`, converts it to a pointer to the array, and dereferences it. The result of the dereference is the array, which is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, and then `x` points to the first element of this one object, and `x[1]` is the second element. However, in `int *x = malloc(2 * sizeof *x);`, there is no array.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The C standard has some text about the type of storage with no declared type, which applies to dynamically allocated space. In this case, I think it says it has the type of the lvalue used to access it. So accessing it with the `int *` means its type is a `float`, not an array of `float`. Therefore, it is a scalar object, and you are not allowed to do pointer arithmetic as if it were an array. (You could point to `x[1]` since it is one beyond the single-element array that a scalar is treated as, but you could not dereference it or point to `x[2]`.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only text describing the representation of arrays is quite terse, and is in what you found at 6.2.5 ¶20:

> Any number of derived types can be constructed from the object and function types, as follows:
>
> - An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type, called the element type. The element type shall be complete whenever the array type is specified. Array types are characterized by their element type and by the number of elements in the array. An array type is said to be derived from its element type, and if its element type is T , the array type is sometimes called ''array of T ''. The construction of an array type from an element type is called ''array type derivation''.

Note that it does not say something like "contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects and padding", so the array **is** just the objects. Thus there seems to be no basis for a claim that `sizeof` the array [type] could yield any result other than the size of the contiguous set of objects, which is obviously `N` times the size of the individual element type.

It's also worth noting that padding is not something that can just exist on its own because it's not specified not to exist. C specifies representations of types (6.2.6) and explicitly specifies the possibility of padding bits and bytes where appropriate. There is no text about padding for arrays, and thus it's not part of their representation.

Comment: At first I thought the word “describes” had some wiggle room, because, if an array “describes” the objects, certainly some data may be needed to provide that description. But, rereading it, I think it means the words “array type” are a description of the type. Thus, the array is the objects.

Comment: Of course, I believe the intent of this passage and those cited in [David Bowling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6879826/david-bowling)’s answer is to make an array just the objects, and these answers move me closer to thinking the standard is accomplishing that, not missing the mark. Not quite the formal statement the mathematician in me wants, but close. I will see what develops for a day or two and then likely accept an answer.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, it is required that the size of an array `T[n]` be `n * sizeof (T)`.

The Standard defines arrays in [§6.2.5/20](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p20):

> An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type....

Further, the `sizeof` operator yields the total number of bytes in the array([§6.5.3.4/4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p4)):

> When **sizeof** is applied .... to an operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array. When applied to an operand that has structure or union type, the result is the total number of bytes in such an object, including internal and trailing padding.

Since an array consists of a contiguous allocation of objects, there can be no internal padding. And since trailing padding is mentioned explicitly with respect to the `sizeof` operator only in the context of unions and structures, it seems clear that arrays are expected to possess no such trailing padding.

Finally, note that in [§6.2.6.1/4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p4) is stated:

> Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of *n* x **CHAR_BIT** bits, where *n* is the size of an object of that type, in bytes. The value may be copied into an object of type **unsigned char [*n*]** (e.g., by memcpy); the resulting set of bytes is called the *object representation* of the value.

Supposing that arrays *could* have trailing padding bytes, consider an array `unsigned char A[n]`, and further consider the array `unsigned char B[sizeof A]`, to which all of the bytes (including possible padding bytes) of `A[]` have been copied. Now, `A[]` *must* be the same size as `B[]`, since ([§6.2.6.1/8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p8)):

> Where an operator is applied to a value that has more than one object representation, which object representation is used shall not affect the value of the result.

This would mean that `B[]` *must* have no trailing padding, which would mean that arrays can have trailing padding bytes except under certain special conditions which are nowhere mentioned in the Standard, or alternatively that arrays may have trailing padding except for arrays of `unsigned char`. Since neither of these possibilities is mentioned in the Standard, it seems reasonable to conclude that arrays must not have trailing padding in the first place.

Comment: See my comments on [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r)’s answer; they apply here too—I think these are good.

Comment: Consequence: on platforms that require alignment, sizeof(struct {int x; char y;}) == sizeof(struct {int x; int y;})

Comment: @Joshua -- not sure that I follow you here. An arbitrary amount of padding may be added to either one of those structures.

Comment: @DavidBowling: Ah yes if the compiler adds padding for the heck of it it won't hold but I've yet to see a compiler that adds padding for the heck of it.

Comment: @Joshua -- indeed, yet I am always wary of meeting the [DeathStation 9000](http://www.statemaster.com/encyclopedia/DeathStation-9000) in a dark alley.

Comment: There is more information in this answer, but I think R..’s answer has the defining text. My initial reading of it, that an array “describes” a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects, was not the intended meaning. It is really saying an array **is** a set (really sequence) of objects. The other items in 6.2.5 20 are also worded with “describes,” but that wording is influenced by the language structure there. It is really the words “array type” that describe a type that is an array. It is not the array or the type that is describing something; the array **is** the set of objects.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- Agree that the essence is captured in the first part of both answers; the additional information I provided was to convince that there is no reasonable way to support the idea that any additional padding could be added to an array, as this is the only way that its size may not be `n * sizeof (T)`.