# C - Address difference between two columns of 3D array

Tags: c, arrays

for the following C code snippet ,

```
int a[2][3][2] = { { {1,2},{3,4},{5,6} },{{7,8},{9,10},{11,12} } };
printf("%d %d",a[1]-a[0],a[1][0]-a[0][0]);
```

This code is giving output `3 6` , But I am not getting this.

I can visualize 3D array `a[2][3][2]` as two `2D` arrays of size 3x2,and its indices like this:

```
a[0][0]--> | 1 2 || 7  8 | <--a[1][0]  
a[0|[1]--> | 3 4 || 9  10|
           | 5 6 || 11 12|
            a[0]    a[1]
```

Let address of `a[0]` be `1000` then address of `a[1]` will be `1012` , assuming size of `int` be 2 bytes.
so `(a[1] - a[0])` should be 12 , but its giving 3. 3 is actually number of rows in the matrix.But,to get number of rows the code should be like this:

`(a[1] -a[0])/(row_size *sizeof(int));`

Similarly, in the case of `a[1][0]-a[0][0]`.

I don't understand this thing.
Please explain.
Thank you.

Comment: You're reading the thing from the left, but the arrays apply sorta "from the right". Using `std::array` syntax might make it clearer.

Comment: "assuming size of int be 2 bytes. so (a[1] - a[0]) should be 12". Nope. when you subtract one pointer from another, the result is in units of the size of the thing pointed to, not in bytes.

Comment: @JeremyP "When you subtract one pointer from another , the result is in units of the size of the thing pointed to , not in bytes" , actually this was the confusion I got , Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets try to write out the array how it looks like in memory:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| a[0][0][0] | a[0][0][1] | a[0][1][0] | a[0][1][1] | a[0][2][0] | a[0][2][1] | a[1][0][0] | a[1][0][1] | a[1][1][0] | a[1][1][1] | a[1][2][0] | a[1][2][1] |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
^                         ^                         ^                         ^
|                         |                         |                         |
a[0][0]                   a[0][1]                   a[0][2]                   a[1][0]
|                                                                             |
a[0]                                                                          a[1]
```

When you do e.g. `a[1] - a[0]` you let the sub-arrays decay to *pointers* to their first element, and the difference between two pointers is in units of their dereferenced types.

So for `a[0]` (and `a[1]`) the type is `int [3][2]`. It decays to a pointer to its first elements, which is of type `int (*)[2]`. The dereferenced pointer will be of type `int [2]`. Now how many `int [2]` are there between `a[0]` and `a[1]`? There are three such elements, so the result of `a[1] - a[0]` is `3`.

If we take `a[1][0] - a[0][0]`, the type of both `a[1][0]` and `a[0][0]` is `int [2]`. It decays to a pointer which is of type `int *`, and the dereferenced type is `int`. And there are six `int` elements between `a[0][0]` and `a[1][0]`.

Comment: now this is someone who got their 3 star programmer certification. :) Great answer btw.

Answer (score 2):

As per [standard 6.5.6p9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9) this is undefined behavior:

> *When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;* the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is ptrdiff_t defined in the  header...

The thing is it would give the desired result in most systems. But think `a[0]` and `a[1]` will belong to the same array `a`. But `a[0][0]` and `a[1][0]` are belonging to different array object and then the pointer will point to two different array objects violating the above rule. That's why the undefined behavior.

Comment: Actually I wanted to understand how to visualize this scenario in 1D contiguous allocation, like it is shown in other answer.Then in 1D where will a[0] and a[1] point to ?

Comment: @sharq.: It would be what is shown - in memory they would mostlikely be laid out in contiguous manner - but standard added a constraint around this as I have shown. `a[0]` is the 2d array object so is `a[1]`. Subsequent subscript on the array will get the element similarly as for 1d array.

Comment: The C standard (ISO 9899:2011 6.2.5/20) enforces that the items are allocated contiguously. Otherwise it would not be an array.

Comment: @Lundin.: For array yes it is. For a single array all the elements are contiguous.But not necessarily for 2 different arrays. `a[0]` and `a[1]` is part of same array. `a[0][0]` and `a[1][0]` are not - consider a case which may implement array acess not using flat address space - next question you will ask would be - "Do you know any?" I would say no - but that doesn't save us from saying that tomorrow if you make one and doesn't make `a[0][0]` and `a[1][0]` same as we consider commnly then yes it won't be violating anything.

Comment: Good spot with the UB.

Comment: The rule applies recursively. `a` is an array. It contains an array of 2D arrays, all items allocated contiguously. In that array, `a[n]` is an array of arrays, all items allocated contiguously. And so on. The only issue here is that C does not allow pointer arithmetic outside the bounds of the array, so if you'd use an `int` pointer to iterate through the inner-most dimension, it would strictly speaking not be allowed to go outside the bounds of the current array. This limitation can however be dodged by using a pointer to character type instead - then it is well-defined as per 6.3.2.3/7.

Comment: @coderredoc nice answer. How about `a[0][0]` and `a[1][0]` referring to their first element: `a[0][0][0]` and `a[1][0][0]`. Per definition in the first line of OP question, these two last elements are part of the same object, so why the *belongs to the same array object* is not a transitive property in this case?

Comment: To clarify, this is _not_ UB because the arrays may not be allocated contiguously. They _must_ be allocated contiguously, this is guaranteed. It is only UB because pointer arithmetic boils down to the additive operators, which in turn has the restriction cited in the answer.

Comment: For example, the following code for printing the whole 3D array is 100% well-defined, assuming `uint8_t` is a character type: `for(uint8_t* i=(uint8_t*)a; (uintptr_t)i<(uintptr_t)a + sizeof(a); i+=sizeof(int))
  {
    printf("%d ", *(int*)i);
  }`

Comment: @Lundin.: Yep it is...because any pointer can be converted to `char*` and then that can be incremented or decrememnted to obtain the result. And yes it is...I have said thtat..I have never said that arrays are not allocated contiguously - multidim array in C is realized via array if array. I am just saying that a[0],a[1] wil be contiguous so will be the elements of [0] but not nceessarily the elements of the two different array. I guess I didnt contradict any of this.

Comment: Does it say in the C standard that an array `int a[n][m]` *must* be allocated as a contiguous block of m x n `int`s?

Comment: @JeremyP: [Yes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522295/does-the-c-standard-require-the-size-of-an-array-of-n-elements-to-be-n-times-the)

Comment: @JeremyP.: Sorry for late reply..I edited my answer to be more specific.