# Is &array[0]==(void*)&array guaranteed to be true?

Tags: c++, arrays

Is a pointer to an arbitrary array equal to a pointer to the array's first element after cast to void*, and independently of the compiler?

I need a template function that takes a pointer to `array[0]` and gives a reference to the array. The code below does the job (at least in gcc and clang), and I would like to know if this is a legal C++ code.

My doubts are caused by the fact, that without cast to void* the code that uses the template would not compile (error message: ``static_cast from 'int *' to 'int (*)[10]' is not allowed").

Thanks in advance. Here is the code:

```
template <std::size_t n,  typename T>
inline T (& p2a( T * ptr))[n]
{  
  return *static_cast<T(*)[n]>( static_cast<void*>(ptr) );
}
```

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think the standard guarantees there must be no padding at the beginning of an array, but it'd be weird if there were.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522295/does-the-c-standard-require-the-size-of-an-array-of-n-elements-to-be-n-times-the?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the address of an array is the same as the address of the array's first element (*i.e.,* there is no padding at the beginning of an array) and a cast to `void*` doesn't change the address, so your code does the right thing. However, it is more straightforward to write it as follows:

```
template <std::size_t n,  typename T>
inline auto p2a(T* ptr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T(&)[N]>(*ptr);
}
```